# Proving that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x+1} = 1 $ using the epsilon-delta definition.

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that the following limit using the epsilon-delta definition:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x+1} = 1 $$

By definition, with $ \epsilon > 0 $, there must be a $ N > x $ so

$$ N > x \implies \lvert \frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x+1} - 1 \rvert < \epsilon $$

I know how to solve more simple problems of this instance, but this function is giving me a hard time because of the separate radical in the numerator, so I'm unable to isolate the $ x $ in one side.

Comment: There exist an $N>0$ such that when $x> N, \cdots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well:
$$\left \lvert \frac {x + \sqrt x} {x + 1} - 1 \right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac {x + \sqrt x} {x + 1} - \frac {x + 1} {x + 1} \right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac {\sqrt x - 1} {x + 1} \right \rvert < \left \lvert \frac {\sqrt x - 1} {x - 1} \right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac 1 {\sqrt x + 1} \right \rvert$$

(Edit: Inequality added. Valid for $x > 1$.)

Now to find some $N$, depending on $\epsilon$, such that for all $x \ge N$, the above is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay, with the last expression I can determine $ N = \sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon - 1} $. It's the first time I find that we use an expression greater than the one we have initially defined. How come is that allowed? For example, if we had something like $ |x-4| < \epsilon $, could I use $ |x-7| < \epsilon $ instead?

Comment: You are right. I have neglected to remove the absolute values since every argument is positive. I should have done that in the first step. On a separate note, your $N$ is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, latex. Should be $ N  = (\frac{1}{\epsilon} - 1)^2 $

Comment: Should be $N = (\frac 1 \epsilon - 1)^2$, and let $\epsilon < 1$ so you don't need to deal with additional cases.

Comment: Why not make things easier?  $\sqrt x-1<\sqrt x$ and $x+1>x$ together imply $$\frac{\sqrt x-1}{x+1}< \frac1{\sqrt x}$$And this last expression is less than any given $\varepsilon>0$ whenever $x>1/\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've have found that several problems of epsilon-delta proofs are very mechanical/basic in the way of solving them while these kinds of problems require a more solid understanding of what the proof involves. Do you have any advice or reference to look more into this? Most of the intro calculus textbooks problems don't even cover exercises of this nature, they stop at basic limits as $ \frac{1}{x} $ or $ \frac{1}{x^{2}} $

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have to find such $M$ that for each $x>M$, our expression will be less than epsilon for each epsilon.
Notice: $|\frac{x+\sqrt x}{x+1}-1|=|\frac{x+\sqrt x-x-1}{x+1}|=|\frac{\sqrt x-1}{x+1}|$.
The last expression is less than $\frac{\sqrt x}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$. Therefore, if we choose $M=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2}}$, we get:

$|\frac{\sqrt x-1}{x+1}|<\frac{1}{\sqrt x}<\frac{1}{\sqrt M}=\varepsilon$